# How to Perl script to move files with specific extension from one folder to another and rename the moved files

Tags: perl, csv, perl-module

I have 2 folders DIR1 DIR2 ,i need to move only files with extension ".csv" only from dir1 to dir2

and rename these file copied files with the timestamp in dir2

```
$dirname = "\\dir1\\"
$dirname2= "\\dir2\\";
$filterstring=".csv";
opendir ( DIR, $dirname ) || die "Error in opening dir $dirname\n";
foreach my $filename (readdir(DIR))
{
      if ($filename =~ m/$filterstring/) {                          
$cfile=$dirname.$filename;
print "\n moving $cfile from $dirname  to $dirname2 \n";
move($cfile,$dirname2);                             
           }}
closedir(DIR);
```

This above code i dveloped moves files with extension ".csv " and also files with filename "abc_csv_uv.txt"
how do i rectify this problem and then rename the moved files...please advise..need help

Comment: do you want the timestamp to be modification time of file or time of rename

Comment: @justintime...timestamp should be the modification timw of file...thnks

Answer (score 4):

```
use strict;
use File::Copy;
use File::stat;
use POSIX qw(strftime);

my $dirname = "\\dir1\\";
my $dirname2 = "\\dir2\\";
my $filterstring = "\\.csv\$";

opendir ( DIR, $dirname ) || die "Error in opening dir $dirname\n";
foreach my $filename (readdir(DIR)) {
    next if not $filename =~ m/$filterstring/;

    my $old_file = $dirname . $filename;
    my $new_file = $dirname2 . $filename . '.' . strftime("%Y%m%dT%H%M%S", localtime(stat($old_file)->mtime));

    print "Moving $old_file to $new_file\n";
    move($old_file, $new_file);
}
closedir(DIR);

1;
```

Comment: @j.w.r...thanks alot......but this renames the file from abc.csv to abc.csv.20120907....i want the renaming to done like...abc_20120907t.csv..can u pls help..

Answer (score 2):

Change the filter to `\\.csv$`

`.` in a regex means any character and $ forces it to be at end of string.

Comment: @bool.dev.thanks alot..how do irename the moved files in dir1 with timestamp...pls help

Comment: @justintime...thanks alot..how do irename the moved files in dir1 with timestamp...pls help

Answer (score 2):

I take it this is in to be done in Windows. Otherwise you could just do

```
mv dir1/*.csv dir2
```

You can use perl's glob in a similar fashion

```
for my $file (glob "dir1/*.csv") {
    move $file, "dir2" or die $!;
}
```

Note: untested, since I am on a mobile device.

You may wish to use the File::Copy module instead. See the documentation for move for more info.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another option:

```
foreach my $filename (grep /\Q$filterstring\E$/, readdir(DIR)){
```

The `grep` will only allow your .csv files to pass from the directory read.  Next, remove the conditional:

```
if ($filename =~ m/$filterstring/) {
```

since `grep` will handle the file name filtering.

Comment: @friedo..thanks!!...how do i rename these moved in dir2 append it with timestamp

Comment: use `POSIX::stat` to obtain file status including modification time. Then use that in your `$cfile`

Answer (score 0):

```
use strict;
use File::Copy;
use File::stat; 

use POSIX qw(strftime); 

my $dirname = "\\dir\\";

my $dirname2 = "\\dir1\\"; 

my $filterstring = "\\.csv"; 

opendir ( DIR, $dirname ) || die "Error in opening dir $dirname\n";

foreach my $filename (readdir(DIR)) {

if ($filename =~ m/$filterstring/)

 my $len=length($filename);

my $v=$len-4;

my $str=substr $filename, 0, $v; 

my $old_file = $dirname . $filename;   

my $new_file = $dirname2 . $str . '_' . strftime("%Y%m%d", localtime(stat($old_file)->mtime)).'.'.'csv'; 

print " $new_file\n"; 

copy($old_file, $new_file);

}

} closedir(DIR); 


i modfied and This works!!


thanks all...
```